# macbook hardware specs INCLUDING battery

Tags: hardware, power

I am looking for where to find my specific computer hardware spec's, including my battery. I have a 2009-10 macbook pro and its needing a new battery. So, I need to find the battery size and make sure I get the right one. Using E OS, Juno 5.0, is there a page I can bring up, like a Spec Page? I know OS X has it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get some additional information about the battery in your system with the following command in the terminal:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

However, you may be better using something like [iFixit's "Identify my Mac" page](https://www.ifixit.com/Info/ID-your-Mac) to get the exact model, and it's also a fairly reputable place to buy replacement batteries from.

Comment: thank you David. putting that into the Terminal brings up very helpful information. I will also check out ifiit's site.

Comment: any  where i can bring up my hardware spec's? Processor, internal ram, hard drive, and other spec's?

Comment: After some digging around, I went to Everymac.com, entered my serial number, answered a few questions and found a pretty accurate summary of my hardware spec's.